# Print value of GDB setting

Tags: gdb

How to print the value of GDB setting? For example if I use the command

```
set width 5
```

Later on I want to know the value of `width`, how to do that? I tried

```
print width
print &width
set width?
```

but none of these printed the value `5`. Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `show width`.

For example:

```
(gdb) set width 100
(gdb) show width 
Number of characters gdb thinks are in a line is 100.
```